# How do I keep the trail for the breadcrumbs till the specific nodes?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

When I create a new node and I assign a tag to it, I can view it from the corresponding taxonomy page. The breadcrumbs seem to follow the trail normally

```
Home>>category>>subcategory
```

until the very leaf node, at which point it indicates only

```
Home>>node
```

Why so? How do I keep the breadcrumb trail from collapsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadcrumbs can sometimes be a bit confusing. In my experience the breadcrumb never behaves 100% as you would want it to behave, if you use it as it comes 'out of the box'.

Luckily also other people got annoyed be the standard breadcrumb (mis-)behaviour so over the years a sea of breadcrumb related modules found its way to drupals module collection. [Here is an overview / comparison with some 10-15 modules listed](https://www.drupal.org/node/533448). Maybe *Breadcrumbs by Path* could suit your needs…

Comment: eventually used crumbs